# Can possession be applied to "Somebody and I" rule such as "Somebody's and my/mine"?

Tags: grammar

I have learned that rather than saying "me and somebody", it is correct to use "somebody and I". This can be done by removing the other person and see the sentence still makes sense.
e.g.

- Somebody is going to work.
- I am going to work. (Not me going to work)
- Somebody and I are going to work.

Can the same rule be applied to a sentence with a possession? Is the sentence below correct?

- Somebody's boots were muddy when we were going to work.
- My boots were muddy when we were going to work.
- Somebody's and my boots were muddy when we were going to work.

Comment: No, not really. Subjects that are joined with a conjunction can count as a plural for verb agreement, but possession with `{-Z₂}`, the noun _-'s_ clitic, is not a matter of agreement with another word in the sentence, but with modifying the actual nouns or pronouns in both parts. And that's too complicated to do with a syntactic rule, as you found out. So we don't do it. If you need to use a complex possessor, use _of_.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, the construction where the noun comes in the second possessive is not used. Only a pronoun is found there ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%27s+*+and+mine&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%27s%20%2A%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%27s%20life%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20blessing%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20name%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20heart%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20views%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20sake%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20mind%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20service%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20friend%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20family%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0)). A check of the pattern "'s and my *" yields no occurrence of this construction ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%27s++and+my+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%27s%20and%20my%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20own%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20mother%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20father%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20Lord%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20brother%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20best%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20lord%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20design%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20room%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20and%20my%20love%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C's%20and%20my%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20own%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20mother%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20father%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20Lord%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20brother%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20best%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20lord%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20design%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20room%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B's%20and%20my%20love%3B%2Cc0)).

You should then say and write this.

- Somebody's boots and mine were muddy when we were going to work.

*or*

- Somebody's boots and my own were muddy when we were going to work.

Comment: You need to separate the apostrophe and the "s" to make Google Ngrams find an apostrophe s. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%27+s+and+my+house%2C+%27+s+house+and+mine&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%27%20s%20and%20my%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%27%20s%20house%20and%20mine%3B%2Cc0). (And you need to click **search** again after you click that link for some reason.) "John's and my boots" is perfectly good English. *Somebody's and my boots* does sound weird to me, but so does *Somebody's boots and mine/my own.*

Comment: @PeterShor 1/ I don't understand, this is not so. I do get all the phrases <<'s and my *>> without separation. 2/ "John's and my boots" might be good English but the cases I find are few and mostly from old sources whereas instances  such as "John's boots and mine" are very frequent nowadays. 3/ Notice also that <<' s and my *>> does not yield any constructions in which "*" is a plain noun; "*" is always a noun in the possessive case.

Comment: My Ngram in the comment shows " ' s and my house" gets roughly as many hits as " 's house and mine". Did you even look at it? ***None*** of these constructions (the OP's and the two that you suggest instead) are used very much. That's why the more common constructions with pronouns are the ones that Ngrams finds.

Comment: @PeterShor I did look at it, and I  just took a more careful look just now; this is what I find. 1/ "at sir Joshua's and my house"
: a case of "I dined at Sir Edward Blacket's at Newby" (Sir Edward Blacket's (home or house, country house, etc), and there is no proper ellipsis, the replacement is not unique) or "He told me that the ring was at my mother's." (2014) 
2/ same as "1/"
3/ 4/ false positive
5/ just as "1/" and "2/"
6/ false positive. This means that there is not one valid case.